# How to use nullable reference type attributes in C#7

Tags: c#, attributes, nullable-reference-types

I got a library which is distributed as source code and I can't force my users to use C# version 8.

I still want to improve the experience for users who are using C# 8 with nullable reference types.

Or in other words: My library must compile with C# 7 but also include information about nullable reference types.

What I have done so far is to define the attributes, `MaybeNull` etc, and my source files start with

```
#if (NETSTANDARD && !NETSTANDARD2_0 && !NETSTANDARD1_6) || (NETCOREAPP && !NETCOREAPP2_0 && !NETCOREAPP2_1 && NETCOREAPP2_2)
#nullable disable warnings
#endif
```

And I have put attributes on properties, arguments return types etc.

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public string Function([AllowNull) param) ...
```

This works but since I can't use `?` and `!` there are few things I haven't found a solution to

- `Generics`, there doesn't seem to be a way to mark generic type parameters as nullable with attributes. i.e. the attribute version of `public async Task<string?> Method(KeyValuePair<string, string?> data)`
- Attributes on properties and fields are ignored inside the class (but works from outside)

```
public class C {
    [AllowNull, MaybeNull]
    private string _field;

    [AllowNull, MaybeNull]
    public string Prop1 => _field; // CS8603, Possible null reference return

    [AllowNull, MaybeNull]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public C() { 
        // CS8618, Non-nullable property 'Prop2' is uninitialized
        // CS8618, Non-nullable field '_field' is uninitialized
    }
}
```

- warning on locals `string local = null;` etc

`nullable disable warnings` solves the last 2 points for my users so it is not important but generics is an issue since I have a lot of async methods. **Is there a way to mark nullable reference types in generics without using `?`?**

Comment: Are you talking about using `Nullable<T>` instead of `?`?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nullable/

Comment: @SᴇM, Nullable<T> is only for value types. I mean nullable reference types, a new feature in C#8

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that is just a package with the attributes (which I already got). It says nothing about how to use them for generics

Comment: Can you define your own version of `NullableAttribute`, and apply it by hand?

Comment: @canton7, unfortunately not. `The NullableAttribute type is for compiler use only - it is not permitted in source` https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md

Comment: Sure the C# 8 compiler will reject it, but the C# 7 compiler should accept it...? It shouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: @canton7, yes, but the attribute is only useful in C# 8

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your library using C# 8 and have others consume those binaries from C# 7 (or earlier). The limiting factor isn't the language but the framework (unless they're compiling your source using an earlier compiler).

NRT annotations use attributes which are defined in the generated assembly automatically. You don't usually see these, and they're matched by name rather than `Type`, meaning that you can consume annotations from multiple assemblies even though they have different annotation types (with the same, well-known names).

That is distinct from attribute such as `MaybeNull` and `NotNullWhen` etc, which are not produced by the compiler, however are also matched by full name meaning you can define them yourself or use a library such as `Nullable`.

All that to say, you should be able to use `?`, `!` and avoid the `#if`/`#endif` stuff you mention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my library is distributed as source code.

Comment: Then I think conditional compilation with `#if`/`#endif` is your only option. A while back, when NRT was new (maybe pre-release, I can't quite remember) it was possible to define your own `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute` and friends internally, then apply them to your API manually, but now that gives CS8335.

Comment: If it's useful, here's an example of annotating a library which can be shared as source in a backwards compatible way: https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/pull/36

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone with the problem :-). Their solution is `#if` around every ? and ! which is not worth the effort for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In the case of xunit's assertions it was worth it, at least in my opinion. Then again I am them :). There aren't many methods to annotate there, and they're used very widely. If you have a lot more surface area or fewer consumers I could see it being less worthwhile.